# SQL JOIN two tables to access all of the data

Tags: mysql

I am needing to connect two tables by id then access any of the data from either of them inside a foreach loop.

I've never done any LEFT JOINS or anything so I'm not sure how to start.

The first table named "sys_acl_levels_members" looks like this:

```
IDMember
IDLevel
DateStarts
DateExpires
TransactionID
```

The other table "Profiles" has many more colums but here are the first few:

```
ID
NickName
Email
```

I need help with writing an SQL to gather all this information, then some ways to access it inside of a foreach loop.

For example if I wanted to get "DateStarts"," DateExpires" From "sys_acl_levels_members" and "NickName" FROM "Profiles" WHERE IDLevel = ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT acl.DateStarts, acl.DateExpires
FROM sys_acl_levels_members acl
LEFT JOIN Profiles p
ON p.ID = acl.IDLevel
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a lil lost. I've only worked with simpler queries.  Can you explain this a little?

Comment: What are LEFT JOIN and ON doing?

Comment: LEFT JOIN joins two tables together, ON is like the "WHERE" condition. Read it like this: "fetch the row from Profiles WHERE p.ID is equal to IDLevel; and fetch it only once. If there is no result, regard the fields from this row as NULL." (that is, return a result even if the LEFT JOIN condition does not match.)